# a^ib^jc^k, i < j < k is a context-sensitive language, how can prove it as a context sensitive

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars, regular-expressions

I've been pondering this question for a long time, that $a^ib^jc^k, i < j < k$ is a context-sensitive language, how we can prove it to be context sensitive or
which grammar can generate such a language.

Comment: Try to modify a grammar for $a^nb^nc^n$.

Comment: hello, you mean modify a grammar for context sensitive for a^nb^nc^n. I tried but cannot figure out ways to solve it, could you please give me a hint? Thanks so much